# How to install Pentaho BI 5.0.1 on Tomcat

Tags: mysql, tomcat, installation, pentaho

I looked through tons of articles, but couldn't find a solution. It seems as if folder structure of `biserver-manual` changes from a version to a version. For example, one guy suggests [here](http://habrahabr.ru/post/187782/) unzipping the archive with folders `administration-console` and `biserver-ce` as a first step of installation process, however, there are no such folders in version 5.0.1. Another guy suggests [here](http://iamraghavan.blogspot.ru/2011/12/installing-pentaho-bi-on-tomcatjboss.html) navigating to `\biserver-manual-ce\pentaho-webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml` to make some editions, but once again there is no such file in a package. When I unzip it, I see only `pentaho.war`, `pentaho-style.war`, `pentaho-data.zip` and `pentaho-solutions.zip`. So, I really need a complete guide of `biserver` installation. What I now have is: Apache Tomcat 8.0 and Apache Ant 1.9.3. I also have MySQL Server 5.5 and want to connect it with Pentaho.

#### EDIT:

I tried these four links:

http://anonymousbi.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/pentaho-bi-server-4-5-0-definitive-mysql-installation-guide/

http://woodlouse.blogspot.ru/2013/01/the-worlds-first-install-guide-for.html

http://habrahabr.ru/post/187782/

http://helicaltech.com/pentaho-5-0-1-ce-integration-mysql-5-0-1-ce-windows-linux-family/

Each one leads to a 404 error and a long list of errors in pentaho.log. I just wonder, who have ever seen Pentaho in work? Is it even possible?

Comment: Is Tomcat 8 certified for Pentaho?

Comment: (Tutorial) Getting Started With Pentaho BI Server 5, Mondrian and Saiku: http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/getting-started-with-pentaho-bi-server-5-mondrian-and-saiku/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I have installed the community edition  on Tomcat 7. I am able to login but I still testing it. Try this tutorial:
http://pentaho-bi-suite.blogspot.com.es/2014/01/installation-of-pentaho-501-ce-with.html

I also took a lot of ideas from here:

http://pablotips.blogspot.com.es/p/installing-tomcat-and-pentaho.html

Some tips:

- The Tomcat distribution come with some folders. Copy the Data, pentaho-solutions and licenses to the same directory as tomcat. You will need it.
- Do not change the name of the the Tomcat they give you: C:\Pentaho\server\biserver-ee\tomcat\webapps but if you change it you need to update solution-path in web.xml
- You need to start the Tomcat with enough memory. Copy the parameters from the start-pentaho.bat. Update the service or the start script.
- You need to configure the "_PENTAHO_JAVA" and "_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME" variables
- In tomcat\webapps\pentaho\META-INF\context.xml docbase should be docBase. This will avoid one warning but I still find errors and warnings in the logs.
- In \webapps\pentaho\docs there is a lot of documentation that can be helpfull.
- Before point 4 "Executing MySQL .sql scripting files for Pentaho Integration" the server should be able to start and work with some demo data in [hsql](http://hsqldb.org/).
- On point 5.III of the tutorial it tells who to change the META-INF/context.xml highlighting the change of URL but forgot to highligth the change of driver to MySQL and validationQuery.
- If you find some Quartz initialization problems see [create an empty table](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?153231-Pentaho-ce-5-Initialization-Exception)

Good look and please report any other finding.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I will have a look at all this at weekends

Comment: You are welcome. I had just edited to add a last point tha I think can be helpfull.